# Print part of the message at the console level, but the entire message to a file using NLog

Tags: c#, nlog

Printing the entire exception object to the console makes it messy. Is there a way to print just `ex.Message` to the console, but the whole object (stack) to a file, and/or when using `Debug` or `Trace`?

Let's say the exception `ex` is `Blah blah..at System.Number.StringToNumber(String... str...:line 269`
The `_log.Error` below should print `Failed to... Error: Blah blah` to console, but `Failed to... Error: Blah blah..at System.Number.StringToNumber(String... str...:line 269` to file or when `_log.Debug` or `_log.Trace` is used.

```
catch (Exception ex)
 {
     _log.Error($"Failed to... Error: {ex}");
 }
```

Should I just write some custom `Console` target as shown [here](https://nlog-project.org/2015/06/30/extending-nlog-is-easy.html) and manipulate the message arguments in some way or there are other easier ways?

Comment: I am pretty sure the NLog console target let's you define a message template.https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Console-target#layout-options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Format`-option on [${exception}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Exception-Layout-Renderer) to control its output:

- `format=Message` to only output Exception-Message
- `format=ToString` to output Exception-ToString()
- etc.

```xml
<nlog throwConfigExceptions="true">
   <targets>
      <target xsi:type="console" name="logConsole" layout="${time}|${level}|${message} ${exception:format=ShortType,Message}" />
   </targets>
   <rules>
      <logger name="*" minLevel="Debug" writeTo="logConsole" />
   </rules>
</nlog>
```

If you like to see full exception detail in console, but only on `LogLevel.Error` then you can do this:

```xml
<nlog throwConfigExceptions="true">
   <variable name="ConsoleInfoLayout" value="${time}|${level}|${message} ${exception:format=ShortType,Message}" />
   <variable name="ConsoleErrorLayout" value="${time}|${level}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=ToString}" />
   <variable name="ConsoleDefaultLayout" value="${when:when=level<=LogLevel.Warn:inner=${ConsoleInfoLayout}:else=${ConsoleErrorLayout}}" />

   <targets>
      <target xsi:type="console" name="logConsole" layout="ConsoleDefaultLayout" />
   </targets>
   <rules>
      <logger name="*" minLevel="Debug" writeTo="logConsole" />
   </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: The `${exception}` has no effect on the exception included in the message. When I do `_log.Error($"Failed to... Error: {ex}");` it still shows the whole exception with stack and exception type. It does however have effect if I just do `_log.Error(ex);`. So, should I write my custom exception serialization and/or `target`?

Comment: @theateist You need to provide the exception as first parameter, instead of including it in the log-message. Ex. `_log.Error(ex, "Failed to execute");` See also https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/How-to-log-exceptions